# Groups API - someGroup.setShowInGroupDirectory(true) - "List this group in the directory" is checked - group not appearing in "Browse All"

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api, google-groups-settings

Google Apps for Business account here.

**SETUP**

I am creating a new group using the Directory API -> all ok.

I am then doing the following:

1. get the Group I just created using the Groups API and assign it
   to "someGroup"
2. invoke "someGroup.setShowInGroupDirectory(true)"
3. patch "someGroup" using the Groups API

No issues on the execution - everything comes back with no complaints.

---

**VERIFY**

I go to the Google Apps Admin console and search for the group I created. All ok - it appears.

I go to the Google Groups homepage for my domain and click "Browse All". ***The Group I created does not appear here.***

I go to the Google Groups / Information / Directory settings page for the Group I created (https://groups.google.com/a/MY_DOMAIN.com/forum/#!groupsettings/MY_GROUP/directory) and observe that "List this group in the directory" ***is*** checked.

However, if at this stage I manually uncheck "List this group in the directory", save, recheck it, save... It does appear in the "Browse All" view. I am trying to build an automated solution and can't really depend on my uses to execute this manual step for every group they create.

I've waited 24+ hours for any background sync to occur and still the group is not appearing in the Browse All view unless I manually toggle as described.

Anyone seen anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the off-chance someone finds this one day: it actually took +-24 hours for the groups to start dropping in.

The first test apparently look just under 25 hours; another subsequent one took around 23.

The painful thing is that if you manually uncheck, save, recheck and save, they appear immediately.